# kendo angular multiple modal overlay

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have 2 modals.
One modal has a button to show another modal on top of it.
how can I adjust the k-overlay to show on first modal when second modal is opened.
currently I have this:

```
<div class="k-overlay" *ngIf="modalOpened"></div>
```

This overlay will show whenever a modal in the system is opened. but it only adds an overlay to the background not the modal

I've tried to play with `z-index` but it's messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ngx-bootstrap" Modal.

- Use "Nested Modal"

Visit https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#directive-nested

Sample Code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="parentModal.show()">Open parent modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #parentModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-nested-name1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="dialog-nested-name1" class="modal-title pull-left">First modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="parentModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="childModal.show()">Open second modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-nested-name2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="dialog-nested-name2" class="modal-title pull-left">Second modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="childModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is second modal <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="thirdModal.show()">Open third modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #thirdModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-nested-name3">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="dialog-nested-name3" class="modal-title pull-left">Third modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="thirdModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is third modal <br>
        Click <b>&times;</b> to close modal.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```